# Difference between Android version in regions

Tags: android-versions, localization

I installed stock ROM for Android 4.4.2 for Colombia region this April. Today while I was surfing the web, I found out that my Android version is slightly different from the one that I saw on web (both devices were the same).

How is this possible? Do the features of updates depends on region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a few parts of the ROM are Region-specific like support for local fonts in that region, apps that come pre-installed based on region like flipkart app in India. And few more things. Even sometimes the ROM are in local languages instead of English.